# Why would my bathroom fan light receptacle not work with LED bulbs?

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan

Replaced the bathroom fan last week with a fan/light combo. It's driven off the same switch for both the fan and the light. I had put in an LED bulb last week when i replaced it and its been working fan, but a few days ago it started flickering a bit when turning on, then today it just would take minutes to turn on.

Thinking the bulb was the problem, I replaced the LED bulb with another LED bulb. Still not turning on.
Thinking then that the wiring might be the problem, I unplugged the light receptacle from the base of the fan/light combo, plugged it into the bathroom gfci outlet, still wouldn't turn on.
Here's the weird part, i plugged in the light receptacle into an outlet in my kitchen and it turned on instantly...
Then i replaced the LED bulb with an incandescent bulb, and it also turned on instantly. In the kitchen outlet, in the bathroom outlet, and in the actual fan base!

This is my first time replacing a fan/light and I just want to make sure i'm not gonna burn my house down...

This is the fan I installed: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Broan-3-5-Sone-70-CFM-White-Bathroom-Fan/3377250

Comment: I take it the fan/light does not have a remote control in it?

Comment: Does it only flicker when the fan is on?  It might be an electrically noisy motor.   LED bulbs are more susceptible to electric noise.

Comment: Sounds like a wiring issue to the fan.  Someone may have put the lamp in series with the fan.

Comment: is the switch normal or special, like a motion detector or timer?

Comment: Nothing fancy about the unit or the switch. No remote control, no motion detector

Comment: Brand & model of all the devices involved, please. No ceiling fan I've ever installed had a light kit that could be plugged into an outlet, so this is a new one on me. (Last fans I installed were just 2 summers ago, so I'm not _totally_ out of date...)

Comment: If the lamp and fan were in series, then the fan wouldn't work when no light bulb is installed.

Comment: From Q&A on the Lowes site: *This fan has been UL approved for use with A19 type 100 Watt maximum incandescent bulb. We cannot recommend using an LED bulb. For additional assistance, please contact our Technical Support Department at 800-637-1453.* "Why" is a good question, because since it can be wired fan/light separate (which I recommend, but you'd need to run new wire to do that) logically there should be no issue. But the manufacturer said so.

Comment: I have two garage door openers (1.5 years old) that will not work with LEDs. Why? IDK.

Comment: The key may be in the time delay - at first it worked for a while in the bathroom, then didn't, then took a while after being removed from the bathroom to work again. Perhaps there is some sort of condensation issue? The bulb is mounted in/near the moist air path, and 100W incandescent would tend to drive moisture away from the bulb base and wiring, while an LED bulb would have much less of a heating/drying effect.

Comment: huh, ok, they said to use an incandescent. At least i wont worry that i messed something up.

Comment: @RetiredATC that is actually a known issue. There are questions on this site about it.

Comment: My bet is there's no back-EMF preventer on the fan motor, so when the motor is cycled off a pulse may "go to" the LED bulb socket and do bad things to the electronics inside the bulb.